# Inside Shiny app, use external R script to generate variables passed to an R Markdown rendering

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am getting crazy with this small reproducible Shiny app:

Basically 3 steps:

1. I have an `input$text` which the user can chose
2. The user triggers an R file `create_text.R` transforming this text, creating a `my_text` string. (IRL it is basically a download and data preparation step)
3. The user triggers the render of an R Markdown where `my_text` value is printed

My base code looks like:

**app.R**

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "text",
              label = "Choose a text",
              choices = c("Hello World!", "Good-bye World!")),
  actionButton("create_text", "Prepare text"),
  downloadButton("report", "Render markdown"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$create_text, {
    text_intermediate <- input$text
    source('create_text.R')
    })
  
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report_test.html",
    content = function(file) {
      rmarkdown::render(input = "report_test.Rmd",
                        output_file = file)
      })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**create_text.R**

```r
my_text <- paste("transfomation //", text_intermediate)
```

**report_test.Rmd**

````
---
title: "My title"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
my_text
```
````

My problem is the intermediate step (2.), probably because I am confused between environments.

- If I run `source('create_text.R', local = FALSE)`, it fails because the R file is run from an empty environment, then does not recognize `text_intermediate`.

```
# Warning: Error in paste: object 'text_intermediate' not found
```

- On the opposite way, if I run `source('create_text.R', local = TRUE)`, the created `my_text` string is not "saved" for the next of the shiny app, then the Rmd cannot be rendered since `my_text is not found`.

```
# Warning: Error in eval: object 'my_text' not found
```

---

What I have tried:

Two ugly solutions would be:

- do not use an intermediate R file and have the whole code inside the app but it will make it very unreadable
- or even more ugly, only use hard assigning `<--` in the R file, like `my_text <<- paste("transfomation //", text_intermediate)`

Playing with the `env` argument of the `render()` function dit not help neither.

Lastly, starting from scratch I would have used reactive values everywhere, but both my R and Rmd files are very big and "finished", and it would be difficult to adapt the code.

Any help ?

Comment: Try `source('create_text.R', local = TRUE)`, it'll use the current (calling) environment instead of global.

Comment: Alternatively, a parameterised markdown may be what you need for your real use case.  Take a look at [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html)...

Comment: You can also write the statement in create_text.R file as a function, then use that function in server.

Comment: @Limey yes, didn’t mention it as possible options, but I’d rather avoid it since there are many variables defined in my script.

Comment: @phago29 it is a good idea indeed buy how would you use it ? If I define it with `create_text <- function() {my_text <- paste("transfomation //", text_intermediate) }` then call `create_text()`, it won't load `my_text` in environment due to "simple" assignation (`<-`)

Comment: @Jrm_FRL You should put a variable inside `function`. For example; `create_text <- function (x) {paste("transformation //", x) }` then call `create_text(text_intermediate)`.

Comment: I see. But IRL, the R file is ~400 lines and I cannot write it under that form. Moreover, I think that the issue would remain the same (the variable would not be kept in environment). No, I think the solution is definitely in using reacting values.

Answer (score 0):

OK, at the end I bypassed the problem with this unelegant solution:

I added a block of code after running the external R script, which stocks all created objects into the global environment. This way, those objects are callable later on in the `server` function. This allows to go without `eventReactive()`. Not very pleasant but works.

For this, I use `assign` within a `lapply`. In my example, it would be equivalent to write: `my_text <<- my_text`. The lapply allows to do it for all objects.

```r
observeEvent(input$create_text, {
  text_intermediate <- input$text
  source('create_text.R')
  lapply(X = (ls()), FUN = function(object) {assign(object, get(object), envir = globalenv())})
})
```